# git navigation expressions

Tags: git

I have encountered following git command: `git diff ^master my_branch@{1} my_branch`. What does `^master`, `my_branch@{1}` and command itself mean?

I looked man for `git diff` but did not found any variants with three branches.

Answer (score 2):

The ^master means not from the master

A ref followed by the suffix @ with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. {1}, {15}) specifies the n-th prior value of that ref. For example master@{1} is the immediate prior value of master while master@{5} is the 5th prior value of master. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log ($GIT_DIR/logs/).

So you do a diff of my_branch, but not show any diffs that are reachable by the master.

Answer (score 2):

See [`gitrevision`](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html) man page for more information. In your example:

1. `my_branch@{1}` means the previous state of `my_branch` reference.
2. `^master` is a feature of `git diff` and means everything except what is already in `master` branch.

In the result you get everything that was in previous version of `my_branch` but is not in `master` yet.